# How to echo value of "id"?

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
{"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48":{
    "id":"115",
    "qty":3,
    "option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",
                          \"value\":\"\"
                         }
              }",
    "price":150,
    "name":"Nightwear",
    "shipping":"5",
    "tax":3,
    "image":"http:\/\/localhost\/plus\/uploads\/product_image\/product_115_1_thumb.jpg",
    "coupon":"",
    "rowid":"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48",
    "subtotal":450
    }
}
```

Hello everyone,
This is my array and I want to echo value of only "id" i.e. I want to get value as '115' of key- "id". Please guide me how to make a foreach for this one? I have tried lots of variations but none worked :(

TIA :)

UPDATE-
I have tried this but did not get any result:

```
foreach($res as $k=>$t)
{
  echo $t["product_details"]["id"]; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put the code in of what you think your best variation is and then we'll help you out.

Comment: You say `foreach`, but the code you post is a JSON for 1 object.

Comment: Hello, I tried json_decode n this but its still not working. Can anyone please give me a working code? Its really urgent

Comment: @user2452 `json_decode` [worked with me](https://eval.in/836362) . The string you posted is a valid JSON.

Comment: @Accountantم Can you please provide me with the working code sir?

Comment: The code you posted seems to be trying to get the ID of productdetails which is nowhere in the data you showed us.

Comment: @user2452 You have to put a reliable example of your array. You put here an object , and I'm sure you have an array , so every answer you are going to get will work on that format of the object in the question but none of them will work with your real array you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of objects like you provided in your post, I have put your object in an array for testing

```
<?php
$json = '[{"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48":{"id":"115","qty":3,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":\"\"}}","price":150,"name":"Nightwear","shipping":"5","tax":3,"image":"http:\/\/localhost\/plus\/uploads\/product_image\/product_115_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"","rowid":"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48","subtotal":450}},'.
         '{"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48":{"id":"116","qty":3,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":\"\"}}","price":150,"name":"Nightwear","shipping":"5","tax":3,"image":"http:\/\/localhost\/plus\/uploads\/product_image\/product_115_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"","rowid":"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48","subtotal":450}}]';
$json = json_decode($json);
foreach ($json as $object){
    $propsArray = get_object_vars($object);
    reset($propsArray);
    echo $object->{key($propsArray)}->id . "<br>\n";
}
exit;
```

this outputs

```
115
116
```

try a live demo (https://eval.in/836364)

Answer (score 3):

Before you can use the JSON as an array you need to convert it first. use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)() for that.

```
<?php 
$json='{"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48":{"id":"115","qty":3,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":\"\"}}","price":150,"name":"Nightwear","shipping":"5","tax":3,"image":"http:\/\/localhost\/plus\/uploads\/product_image\/product_115_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"","rowid":"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48","subtotal":450}}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with this code is it's is looping in the outer object **properties**. And lucky you are the outer object has only 1 property, that is `2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48`and this property is an object too that has the rest of the other data. Your code will not work if this object is an element in an array.

Comment: BTW, this is not your fault, this is the OP fault because he didn't provide a reliable example of the array, your code answers the question 100%

Comment: Yeah I was gona say that lol Anyway, he looks happy with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$json='{"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48":{"id":"115","qty":3,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":\"\"}}","price":150,"name":"Nightwear","shipping":"5","tax":3,"image":"http:\/\/localhost\/plus\/uploads\/product_image\/product_115_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"","rowid":"2b44928ae11fb9384c4cf38708677c48","subtotal":450}}';

$array = json_decode($json, true); // convert json string to array

$result = array_column($array, 'id'); // find matching array key and return values in array

foreach ($result as $value) { // echo each value with foreach loop
    echo $id . '<br>';
}
```